# creating soap webservices and generating wsdl in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-services, soap, wsdl

I have found enough support for creating webservices using soap in java. But not able to find much support on creating soap web services in python.

Got soaplib https://pypi.python.org/pypi/soaplib? but support is less. Please suggest some useful libraries for SOAP in python

Answer (score 1):

soaplib worked fine for me with django.  All of the cool kids are using REST api's and slinging JSON back and forth.  But I like XML.  XML is like violence, if it doesn't solve your problem, you are not using enough.

```
stackoverflow.com/questions/15436749/how-to-call-soap-api-with-python
www.diveintopython.net/soap_web_services/
stackoverflow.com/questions/18175489/python-soap-using-requests
```